# Sorting React State Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

i am unable to sort array of objects stored in react hook state. This array is provided to flat list after being sorted.

```
const { notifications } = useContext(MainContext);
const [sortedNotifications, setSortedNotifications] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    setSortedNotifications(
        [...notifications].concat([]).sort(function(x, y){
            return new Date(y.created_at).getTime() - new Date(x.created_at).getTime();
        })
    )
}, [notifications]);

return <View style={{ flex: 1,  backgroundColor: "white", }}>
    {notifications !== null && notifications.length > 0 ? <FlatList 
        vertical
        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingRight: 20, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 20, paddingTop: 20}}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        style = {styles.flatListStyle}
        data = {sortedNotifications} 
        keyExtractor = {(item,i) => `key-${item.title}-${i}`}
        renderItem = {({ item }) => {
        return <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} style={styles.viewStyle} onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Notification", { n: item })}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{Capitalize(item.title)}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.text2Style}>Received {moment.utc(item.created_at).fromNow()}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    }}></FlatList> : <View></View>}
</View>
```

there is no change in the position of the objects. any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so after 4-6 hours of trying i finally found the solution.
The problem originates from the ECMAScript timestamp format.

The format of my timestamp : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"

Supported ECMAScript timestamp : "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS" - the "T"

Working code:

```
const sorted = notifications.slice().sort((x, y) => {
      var dateStringX = x.created_at.replace(" ", "T");
      var dateStringY = y.created_at.replace(" ", "T");
            
      return new Date(dateStringY).getTime() - new Date(dateStringX).getTime(); 
});

setNotifications(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure from the code, but what is notification.created_at ? is that in epochmilli? is it just a number? If so, no need to convert it to a Date and then run .getTime(). You should be able to just sort x.created_at - y.created_at. That's probably where the problem may be.

Also, as an aside you could simplify this code a bit to something like:

```
const { notifications } = useContext(MainContext);
const sortedNotification = [...notifications].sort((x, y) => x.created_at - y.created_at);

return (... your view)
```

Doing it this way will save you a re-render, since you don't have to setState.

Hope that helps!